# How to get Android pixel RGB array for Keras Model

Tags: android, tensorflow, keras, pixel

So from an online tutorial I have the following lines of code

```
public float[] getPixelData(Bitmap imageBitmap) {
    if (imageBitmap == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int width = imageBitmap.getWidth();
    int height = imageBitmap.getHeight();

    // Get 28x28 pixel data from bitmap
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    imageBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    float[] retPixels = new float[pixels.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; ++i) {
        // Set 0 for white and 255 for black pixel
        int pix = pixels[i];
        int b = pix & 0xff;
        retPixels[i] = (float) ((0xff - b) / 255.0);
    }
    return retPixels;
}
```

This lines of code gives me the black and white colors for the model, however my own model needs RGB colors, and I cam getting the following error in android studio

***Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input and filter must have the same depth: 1 vs 3***

Anyone has any idea how I can convert the code to RGB array for my keras model?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
int width = imageBitmap.getWidth();
int height = imageBitmap.getHeight();

float[] floatValues = new float[width * height * 3];
int[] intValues = new int[width * height];

imageBitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

for (int i = 0; i < intValues.length; ++i) {
  final int val = intValues[i];
  floatValues[i * 3 + 0] = (((val >> 16) & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
  floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = (((val >> 8) & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
  floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = ((val & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
}
```